# Print list of actual employees in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I use the following script to generate a list of employees.

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties DisplayName,mobile,EmailAddress | select DisplayName,mobile,EmailAddress | export-csv AD-Users-EmployeeID.csv -Encoding unicode
```

The results include a bunch of test accounts with different names.

Is there a way to limit the result to accounts that contain an emplyee number or eployee ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[...] -Filter 'employeeID -like "*"' [...]
```

Or:

```
Get-ADUser [...] | ? {$_.employeeID -ne $null} | Select [...]
```